# Add START and STOP buttons to existing code

Tags: excel, vba, timer

Enter a value in column A.
To start, double click value in column A.
To stop, double click any blank cell.
Stop watch run in cell B2.

```
Public stopMe As Boolean
Public resetMe As Boolean
Public myVal As Variant


Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        If Target.Value = myVal And Target.Value <> "" Then
            'Changed
            Dim startTime, finishTime, totalTime, timeRow
            startTime = Timer
            stopMe = False
            resetMe = False
            myTime = Target.Offset(, 2).Value
            Target.Offset(, 1).Select
startMe:
            DoEvents
            timeRow = Target.Row
            finishTime = Timer
            totalTime = finishTime - startTime
            Target.Offset(, 1).Value = Format(800 + totalTime, "0000")
            If resetMe = True Then
                Target.Offset(, 1).Value = 0
                Target.Offset(, 2).Value = 0
                stopMe = True
            End If
            If Not stopMe = True Then
                Target.Offset(, 2).Value = totalTime
                GoTo startMe
            End If
            Cancel = True
            End
        Else
            'Not Changed
            stopMe = True
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    myVal = Target.Value
End Sub
```

I want to make buttons for start, stop & reset and link with this code but can't able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code to create buttons.  Once you have the buttons on your worksheet, move them to your desired locations, resize them, and assign code to them:

```
Sub ThreeButtons()
   ary = Split("Start,Stop,Reset", ",")
   t = 10
   For i = 1 To 3
      Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(5, 100, t, 60, 60)
      shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = ary(i - 1)
      shp.ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset & (40 - i)
      t = t + 70
   Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Adapted from:  [peltiertech](http://peltiertech.com/programming-excel-2007-2010-autoshapes-with-vba/)